# Исключение ImageCodecException, при загрузке изображения с сервера

Tags: flutter

Мне нужно получить изображение с сервера, для выпадающего меню. В переменную userAvatarUrl я буду получать прямую ссылку на картинку. Но NetworkImage выдает исключение `ImageCodecException`
Сам код:

```
class Menu_main extends StatelessWidget {
  var userAvatarUrl = 'https://dere.shikimori.one/system/characters/original/70069.jpg';
  @override
  Drawer build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          new DrawerHeader(
            margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            child: UserAccountsDrawerHeader (
              currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                foregroundImage: NetworkImage(userAvatarUrl),
              ),
              accountName: Text('Логин'),
              accountEmail: Text("Почта"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Изображения, включенные в проект выводятся нормально. Попытался использовать `Image.network(userAvatarUrl)`, но опять было вызвано исключение `ImageCodecException` код:

```
new DrawerHeader(
            margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Material(
                    child: Image.network(userAvatarUrl),
                  ),
                  UserAccountsDrawerHeader (
                    accountName: Text('Логин'),
                    accountEmail: Text("Почта"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ),
```

Как правильно загрузить изображение с сервера? Версия Flutter 2.0.3 версия Dart 201.9335 делаю под телефоны.

Comment: `Flutter web` или мобильная?

Comment: Одно из решений настроить [CORS](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web-images#cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors)

Comment: Я делаю приложение под телефоны, в 1.* версиях flutter все работало нормально, без настроек CORS, сейчас я использую стороннюю библиотеку, и все работает без проблем, но хотелось бы минимизировать использование сторонних библиотек.

Comment: ну посмотрите как это делает библиотека...